# What prevents Excel from staying current with the years. For instance, why aren't I using Excel 2015?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Just curious on why Excel (along with other Microsoft applications) are not "up-to-date".

Comment: They are up to date with "updates" for as long as the product is supported. Office versions are different products.

Comment: What do you mean by current? Do you mean why doesn't Excel 2015 exist?

Answer (score 3):

That is because they are very large, complex applications that take a lot of work to produce new, stable versions. So even with the resources of Microsoft, it takes a long time to churn out a new major version. That's the techie view.

There is also the marketing/sales view. Which is that you have to balance the release of new versions with what people are prepared to pay.

Then there is the enterprise view (enterprises are the ones paying the big bucks to Microsoft for 000's of copies of the software). Here, the balance is that it takes a lot of time, energy and cost to test, release and train for a new version of Office software. So again, too many releases cause major headaches for enterprises.

Of course, all of this is about to change. Microsoft, along with many others, are rapidly moving all of their major software to rapid release cycles. Here, they release small updates often rather than large updates rarely. The drivers for this are both the expectations of users - which have massively changed due to the increased exposure to IT in personal lives. Also the move towards cloud solutions where large updates are difficult and sometimes dangerous (the service often becoming wildly unstable). Small updates are easier to manage with modern approaches to development & modern tools.

Office 2016 is quite likely to be the last monolithic release of Office with Microsoft then moving to monthly patches (for security and stability releases) and 6 monthly feature releases. This will be in line with Microsoft's other major lines such as Windows and SharePoint.